# How can I save and recall a plot in mathplotlib without recalculating it each time?

Tags: python, plot, graphics

first of all, python newbie here so there's a lot I don't know.

What I'm trying to do is generate a grid of contour plots, each of which is the output of a custom python package (not written by me, obviously) that eats up a lot of resources. I can make these plots one at a time no problem, but if I try to make more than one at once like with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0,0].contourf(blah blah)
ax[1,0].contourf(blah blah)
ax[0,1].contourf(blah blah)
ax[1,1].contourf(blah blah)
plt.show()
```

it chokes and gives me "allocation failed" error. I've been googling around looking for a way to name each of these plots so they can be called later and inserted into a large grid of them. Either there isn't really a way to do this or I'm so unfamiliar with the jargon that I can't see it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can just save the values to `lists` and plot the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you would **create the data first**.

If you did not want to recompute the data, then you would load it (for example from a csv file, database or other source).

All of the plotting starts afterwards.

So, the structure of the code would look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

######### the data goes here ##########
# in the case of the question this is pre-saved data
#######################################
# Generate coordinate grids (X,Y) and Z values.
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 30)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = (1 - X/2 + X**5 + Y**3) * np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)


######## the plot goes here ##########

# Create contour plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax: matplotlib.axes.Axes
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
ax.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X') 
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

The result (of this particular example), looks like this:
[image]